# Downloading HTML5 edited <audio> tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, audio, download

I am editing a local audio file using the html5's audio tag with javascript/angularjs through the app. I want to download such file with all the edited properties of the  object. I can't find anywhere if this is possible.